# SharePoint find and delete file

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, document-library, pnp-powershell, file

A cyber attack generated thousands of files in SharePoint with this name "Read_me_now.htm".

In PowerShell with the command `Find-PnPFile -Match * read_me_now.htm *` I display them.

With what command can I search for them and then delete them? I tried with `Remove-PnPFile -Match * read_me_now.htm *` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this PowerShell code:

```
#Get all matching files
$Files = Find-PnPFile -Match *read_me_now.htm

#Delete all files
ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-Host ("Deleting File: '{0}' at '{1}'" -f $File.Name, $File.ServerRelativeURL)
     
    #Delete Item
    Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $File.ServerRelativeURL -Force -Recycle
}
```

This will move files to recycle bin. If you want to permanently delete the files, change `Remove-PnPFile` line to this:

```
Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $File.ServerRelativeURL
```

**Documentation**:

1. [Find-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/find-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)
2. [Remove-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Hi @Tomato1287, did you try this PowerShell? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below script to delete files with "**read_me_now.htm**" extension as an admin：

```
$SiteURL = "https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$LibraryName = "Documents"

#Credentials: The account and password of the site administrator
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

$Files = Find-PnPFile -List "Documents" -Match *read_me_now.htm

ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-Host ("Deleting File: '{0}' at '{1}'" -f $File.Name, $File.ServerRelativeURL)
    
    #Delete Item
    Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $File.ServerRelativeURL -Force -Recycle
        
}

#Empty Reycle Bins:Permanently deletes all the items in the 1st stage and 2nd Stage recycle bins of which the file names have the "read_me_now.htm" extension

Get-PnPRecycleBinItem | Where-Object LeafName -like "*read_me_now.htm" | Clear-PnpRecycleBinItem -Force
```

**Reference:**

- [Find-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/find-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [Remove-PnPFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/remove-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)
- [Clear-PnPRecycleBinItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/clear-pnprecyclebinitem?view=sharepoint-ps)