# Finding and Deleting All Instances of Files Matching a Specific Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, file, powershell-script

Is there a way of being able to find files within multiple Document Libraries matching a specific name and deleting all of them?

I have written a script using the Find-PnPFile and Remove-PnPFile cmdlets but for some reason it does not appear to be working.

```
$SiteURL = "https://example.sharepoint.com/site/"

#Credentials: The account and password of the site administrator
Connect-PnPOnline -URL $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)

$Files = Find-PnPFile -Match *File.exe

ForEach ($File in $Files)
{
    Write-Host ("Deleting File: '{0}' at '{1}'" -f $File.Name, $File.ServerRelativeURL)
    
    #Delete Item
    Remove-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $File.ServerRelativeURL -Force -Recycle
        
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Are you not able to find the matching files using `Find-PnPFile` command? Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299053/sharepoint-find-and-delete-file/299054#299054). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried Find-PnPFile and I am getting Find-PnPFile: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. although the address is correct (along with the credentials) and reachable.

Comment: Can you try using this & check if it throws same error: `$Files = Find-PnPFile -Match *.pdf` **OR** `$Files = Find-PnPFile -Match *.exe`

Comment: Ganesh, what I get is:

Comment: My mistake.  Must have been been a faulty session.  Running the command in a new session does not give me any errors.  Basically the same scenario as the script.  Blinking cursor.

Comment: In my above comment I have given two separate commands to try out and you tried to run it as a single command hence error in your above comment. Is it working for you now, in new session?

Comment: That is what I had figured.  Having tried each I simply get a blinking cursor with no results or output.  Having tried the same approach previously overnight there were no results.  The site nor the document libraries are not very large.